# React [Advanced] - Is it possible to force update by reference to fiber node?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do requires access to react internals and probably should not be done in everyday use.

I'm trying to force the update of any React component only having access to its Fiber node and nothing else.

I've got access to some Fiber node using

```
function getCurrentFiber() {
  // Again - we're digging into dark places here. 
  return React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner.current
}
```

called during rendering eg.

```
function Component() {
  window.fiber = getCurrentFiber();
  return <div>foo</div>
}
```

This way I've got access to fiber node of Component instance.

I'm trying to force update of Component using it.

I've figured out a bit hacky way to do it, but it works only with Class components:

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component,  } from 'react';

export function createForceUpdateByFiber() {
  /**
   * To pick force update, we need to render class component and
   * get force update from it's internals
   */

  let forceUpdate = null;
  class Capture extends Component {
    render() {
      
      /**
       * Each class component has such option that allows passing
       * instance of the component to perform ForceUpdate fiber update
       */
      forceUpdate = this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate
      return null;
    }
  }

  // let's render
  const holder = document.createElement('div');

  render(<Capture />, holder);
  
  // now we have this force update function picked

  // let's prepare function that accepts fiber instance
  function performForceUpdateByFiber(fiber) {
    /**
     * enqueueForceUpdate requires the instance to be passed,
     * but the instance is only used to get corresponding fiber.
     * 
     * Under the hood it expects fiber to be under ._reactInternalFiber
     * key. So let's prepare such object
     */
    
    forceUpdate({_reactInternalFiber: fiber});
    
  }

  return performForceUpdateByFiber;
}
```

Now. If having that, we render Class component like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    window.fiber = getCurrentFiber();

    return (
      <div>Class component ({Math.random()})</div>
    );
  }
}
```

and later on we call

```
const forceUpdateByFiber = createForceUpdateByFiber();
forceUpdateByFiber(window.fiber);
```

The class component gets re-rendered! (We can confirm by seeing different random numbers being rendered.

However, if I try to perform the same with Functional component by rendering

```
function Component() {
  window.fiber = getCurrentFiber();
  console.log('Component render call');
  return <div>Functional component ({Math.random()})</div>
}
```

and then

```
const forceUpdateByFiber = createForceUpdateByFiber();
forceUpdateByFiber(window.fiber);
```

It calls Component function (confirmed by console.log), but the result is never flushed to DOM.

It's probably because only class components have 'forceUpdate' feature by default. It is possible to create useForceUpdate hook etc, but technically it's just state hook and I'm trying to force the update of any component by having access to only its fiber.

---

Note: I'm not asking for ways to force component update 'react' way. There are many ways and I know how to use them.

I'm trying to perform the update only having access to internal react Fiber.